# Web Services not working after project upgrade from VS2008 to VS2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have an old Web Site Project (VB.NET 3.5) written with Visual Studio 2008. I need to port this to VS2013 (no license for a newer VS). I openend the .sln with VS2013 and it converted the sln (there is no .vbproj for Web Site Projects). There were no errors.

My WSP consumes web services (they are still online and working). But now in VS2013 i get the error message "Type 'com.foo.bar.webservice" is not defnied.

So I removed the web service from "App_WebReferences" and added it again:

1. Add > Service Reference
2. on dialog "Add Service Reference" i clicked on "Advanced..."
3. on dialog "Service Reference Settings" i clicked on "Add Web
   Reference..."
4. on dialog "Add Web Reference" i typed the correct url
   and a web service was discovered of course I choose the Web
   reference name: com.foo.bar.webservice I clicked on "Add Reference"
5. now I got 3 files generic.disco, generic.discomap, generic.wsdl. generic.disco, generic.discomap they are identical to those of VS2008. The generic.wsdl has a different xmlns name space, except of that - identical.

But: although the files are created, i cannot use the web reference. I searched the object explorer - nothing. So

```
Dim service As New com.foo.bar.webservice.MyService
```

throughs the "Type is not defined error".

If I create with VS2013 a new Web Forms Application VB.Net 3.5 i can add the web reference and use it. But I get different files (Reference.map, Reference.vb, ...)

So my question is: Why can't I add an old fashioned "Web Reference" after I upgraded my Web Site Project from VS2008 to VS2013?

Any suggestions are welcome!